# Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Content)) displays html tags

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, tags, tinymce

I am using tinyMce in asp.net mvc4 app. I managed to save the content of textarea to database by setting encoding:"xml" for tinyMce textarea. However I am not able to display raw html by using:

```
  @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Content))
```

It still displays html tags in the text. Can somebody help me to display just the content, so the html tags will not be "escaped".

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would look at your data.  I ran into something similar and found that my data was saving with ascii tags in it.  the editor was translating those ascii tags and showing html tags instead of rendering.  I created two simple methods to convert

```
public string Decode(string value)
    {
        return (value)
            .Replace("&quot;", "\"")
            .Replace("&lt;", "<")
            .Replace("&gt;", ">");
    }

    public string Encode(string value)
    {
        return (value)
          .Replace("\"", "&quot;")
          .Replace("'", "''")
          .Replace("<", "&lt;")
          .Replace(">", "&gt;");
    }
```

and ran my string through that going to the database and back and it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you for answer, after horibly long time I found out that I was encoding the content once with tinyMce and once in c# controller so I double encoded it, so this was my problem. And right as you sayed my data was saving with ascii tags